# What is the meaning of planning a journey to smallest details?

Tags: meaning

Son telling about his father.

> Dad's expeditions always included a journey. And he always planned
>   them, **down to the smallest details**.

Comment: It's always worth looking in the dictionary before posting a question.. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/down%20to%20the%20smallest/last/tiniest%20detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some people plan a long car trip by deciding

- Who is going
- What car they are taking.
- What city they are going to.
- What day they are leaving.
- What day they are coming back.

Those people expect to find restaurants along they way. The will look at the restaurants and decide where to stop to eat.  When they see the gas tank is getting low they will start looking for a gas station.

The father in your question is not one of those people.

The father in your question decided all the details before the trip.  The father planned where they would eat breakfast and at what time.  The father planned where they would eat lunch and at what time. He even planned what they would order and knew how much it would cost because he called the restaurant before the trip. When they went in the restaurant the father told them how much time they had available to eat. The father planned what each person would wear on each day of the trip. He planned which hotels they would stay at. He planned what time they would go to sleep and wake up. He planned what TV shows they would watch at the hotel and how much time they would spend at the swimming pool and at what time each child would take a shower. He planned everything.